# Writing txt to file without appending

Tags: java, string, io

Okay so I am implementing a system were I am keeping a count saved in a `.txt` file.

The count is an integer.

The only issue I have, is that instead of replacing the previous count; e.g

```
"78" -> "79"
```

It is adding the new count to the previous count; e.g

```
"78" -> "7879"
```

My code is:

```
private static void saveCount(int inCount) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    BufferedReader fbr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("count.txt"));
    try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("count.txt", (fbr.readLine() != null))) {
        String count = Integer.toString(inCount);
        fw.write(count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The second parameter of the `FileWriter` constructor is a boolean flag `append`. Set it to false to overwrite the file instead of appending.

Answer (score 3):

You are enabling appending. Replace `(fbr.readLine()!=null)` with `false` to disable appending, as shown below:

```
private static void saveCount(int inCount) throws FileNotFoundException, 
        IOException {
    BufferedReader fbr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("count.txt"));
    try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("count.txt", false)) {
        String count = Integer.toString(inCount);
        fw.write(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: @JunedAhsan It works perfectly. Perhaps something was broken in a previous edit?

Comment: Note: you can remove the `BufferedReader` from your answer as it's no longer needed.

Comment: I know, but i didn't wanted to violate the user original code and just put what will solve the problem.

Comment: -1, "didn't wanted to violate the user original code" isn't an excuse for leaving useless crud in code. You already removed the only part where `fbr` is _used_, so why not finish the job?

Answer (score 1):

Constructor of FileReader that you use have a parameter append (of boolean). In case if it true - you will append content of file (and have 7879). In case if it false - content of file will be overridden.

So seems like fbr.readLine() is not null, so you append content each time.

Answer (score 1):

Use a BufferedWriter insted of a BufferedReader and close it when you are done.

```
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("count.txt"));
    out.write(Integer.toString(inCount));
    out.close();
```